# "Domain error in arguments." with "stats.beta.rvs"

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I meant to modle Thompson sampling, but the following code gives Domain error in arguments.
I search about it and find someone says it may because Beta's parameters are negative, but here the paraameters must be positive,I have no idea how to fix it.

```
from scipy import stats   
class TS():
    def __init__(self,alpha,beta,n):
        self.alpha=alpha
        self.beta=beta
        self.n=n
        self.value=[0,0,0]#estimator
        self.prob=[0.4,0.6,0.8]
    def generate(self):
        for j in range(self.n):
            tmp=[0,0,0]
            for i in range(0,3):
                tmp[i]=stats.beta.rvs(self.alpha[i],self.beta[i])
            max_index=tmp.index(max(tmp))
            r=np.random.choice([0,1],p=(1-self.prob[max_index],self.prob[max_index]))
            self.alpha[max_index]+=r
            self.beta[max_index]-=(1-r)
        print(self.value)
one=TS([1,1,1],[1,1,1],100)
one.generate()
```

error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-9df20b1a6a3b> in <module>()
     23         print(self.value)
     24 one=TS([1,1,1],[1,1,1],100)
---> 25 one.generate()

<ipython-input-18-9df20b1a6a3b> in generate(self)
     16             tmp=[0,0,0]
     17             for i in range(0,3):
---> 18                 tmp[i]=stats.beta.rvs(self.alpha[i],self.beta[i])
     19             max_index=tmp.index(max(tmp))
     20             r=np.random.choice([0,1],p=(1-self.prob[max_index],self.prob[max_index]))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in rvs(self, *args, **kwds)
    938         cond = logical_and(self._argcheck(*args), (scale >= 0))
    939         if not np.all(cond):
--> 940             raise ValueError("Domain error in arguments.")
    941 
    942         if np.all(scale == 0):

ValueError: Domain error in arguments.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.beta[max_index]` should be *increased* by `1 - r`.  Change the line that updates `self.beta[max_index]` to

```
        self.beta[max_index] +=  1 - r
```

See Algorithm 2 on page 15 of https://web.stanford.edu/~bvr/pubs/TS_Tutorial.pdf.

Comment: Thank you, Mr.Weckesser. I now understand the missing point. The tutorial you mentioned is so nice!